# $\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2 + n(\bar{y} - \mu)^2$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mean

I have the following example:

> Let $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ be an i.i.d. $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Note that $\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2 + n(\bar{y} - \mu)^2$.
>
> We show that $\sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2_{n - 1}$.
>
> By the equality
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \mu)^2 = \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 + \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} n(\bar{Y} - \mu)^2,$$
>
> we have that the left-hand side is
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_n^2,$$
>
> and the term in the right-hand side is
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} n(\bar{Y} - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_1^2,$$
>
> and so $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \sim \chi_{n - 1}^2$$

How did the author conclude that $\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2 + n(\bar{y} - \mu)^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be shown via variable addition and subtraction:
$$\begin{align}\sum (y_i-\mu)^2&=\sum(y_i-\bar y +\bar y -\mu)^2\\&=\sum(y_i-\bar y)^2+\sum(\bar y-\mu)^2 + \sum2(y_i-\bar y)(\bar y - \mu)\\&=\sum(y_i-\bar y)^2+n(\bar y-\mu)^2 + 2(\bar y - \mu)\underbrace{\sum(y_i-\bar y)}_0\\&=\sum(y_i-\bar y)^2+n(\bar y-\mu)^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What property is $\sum(y_i-\bar y +\bar y -\mu)^2 = \sum(y_i-\bar y)^2+\sum(\bar y-\mu)^2 + \sum2(y_i-\bar y)(\bar y - \mu)$?

Comment: $$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$$

Comment: Thanks! And how do we know that $2(\bar y - \mu)\underbrace{\sum(y_i-\bar y)}_0$?

Comment: $\sum (y_i-\bar y)=\sum y_i - \sum \bar y = n\bar y - n\bar y = 0$

Comment: Ahh, yes: The equation of the sample mean is $\bar{X} = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n X_j$.